# How do I add a mouse over tooltip to an Image using .DrawImage()

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, tooltip, drawimage

Hey all, I am not sure if this is possible, but I am trying to dynamically add a tooltip to an image using the Graphics method - DrawImage. I dont see any properties or events for when the image is moused over or anything so I don't know where to begin. I am using WinForms (in C# - .NET 3.5). Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you have some sort of `UserControl` and you call `DrawImage()` in the `OnPaint` method.

Given that, your tooltip will have to controlled explicitly. Basically, create a `Tooltip` on your Form, give that to your control via a property, show the tooltip when your control received a `MouseHover` event and hide the tooltip when you receive a `MouseLeave` event.

Something like this:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        // draw image here
    }

    public ToolTip ToolTip { get; set; }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);

        if (this.ToolTip != null)
            this.ToolTip.Hide(this);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseHover(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnMouseHover(e);

        if (this.ToolTip == null)
            return;

        Point pt = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        String msg = this.CalculateMsgAt(pt);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
            return;

        pt.Y += 20;
        this.ToolTip.Show(msg, this, pt);
    }

    private string CalculateMsgAt(Point pt) {
        // Calculate the message that should be shown 
        // when the mouse is at thegiven point
        return "This is a tooltip";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, you have to **store bounds** of the Image that you are drawing
and in the `mouseMove event` check if the location of `current Mouse cursor` at that region, then display ToolTip else hide it.

```
    ToolTip t; 
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         t = new ToolTip();  //tooltip to control on which you are drawing your Image
    }

    Rectangle rect; //to store the bounds of your Image
    private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        rect =new Rectangle(50,50,200,200); // setting bounds to rect to draw image
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(yourImage,rect); //draw your Image
    }

    private void Panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (rect.Contains(e.Location)) //checking cursor Location if inside the rect
        {
            t.SetToolTip(Panel1, "Hello");//setting tooltip to Panel1
        }
        else
        {
            t.Hide(Panel1); //hiding tooltip if the cursor outside the rect
        }
    }
```