# C#: Add a ToolTip to an Image

Tags: c#

I have a class that draws images. (This works fine)
I want a toolTip to be displayed when the user hover over the image with the mouse.

In the class's I have:

```
public Graphics Graphic { get; set; } //Element to draw on

SomeMethod()
{
    Symbol = new Bitmap("C:/Test.JPG");
    Position = new Point(100, 300);

    Graphic.DrawImage(Symbol, Position);
    //Here I want to somehow add the ToolTip to the image
}
```

There are lot of examples on how to add the ToolTip to a Control but the Image (as I can see it) is not a control and therefore gives an error when I try to.

Am I not looking at the correct path to be adding tooltips to an image or is the Tooltip class not designed to do this?

Comment: You may find this question similar to what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295372/how-do-i-add-a-mouse-over-tooltip-to-an-image-using-drawimage

Comment: I'ld prefer `SomeMethod(Graphics Graphic)`: you really need to avoid to store a Graphics object in any way. You are drawing on the surface of a control in any case. You could store a reference of the control you're using as canvas and subscribe to its `MouseMove` event. Then check whether the mouse pointer is inside the Rectangle described by your Images and, if it is, display a ToolTip related to the current Image. You just need to have means to relate an Image to a Rectangle. Welll, you already have location and Bitmap size. Otherwise, build a User/Custom Control (probably better).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think `tooltip` is supported in your case, you either have two options

Use a `Control` like `Label` and put image in that ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16888310/5552166) link)

or implement your own `tooltip` based on mouse events([this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81f8a658-867a-4f07-aac7-0075db0399c5/tool-tip-on-a-bitmap-graphic?forum=vbgeneral) link should give you the idea)